# Assign multiple members to other members?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In Umbraco 7, is there anyway to create a field on a Member, where an administrator can assign multiple Members to another Member of a different Member Type?

For example, we have 2 Member, "Dealers" and "Distributors".  We would like to have a field to allow multiple "Distributors" to be associated with a "Dealer".

I know Umbraco has a "Member Picker" data type, but that looks like you can only assign a single Member.  I'm guessing I might have to create a custom data type, if it's even possible with Umbraco.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to create a custom datatype, you could just create a new Multinode Treepicker data type and switch the Node type from "Content" to "Members" using the drop down.  This will allow the user to select multiple members.  You can also limit the picker to only allow members of a certain type by entering a list of allowed Member type aliases.